# Spring Security Logout does not kill session

Tags: spring, security

I am using spring security logout to implement logout.My spring configuration is

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="customLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <logout success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,Helix"/>
</http>
```

I have implemented this LogoutSuccessHandler(implements SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler) by overriding onLogoutSuccess method and in it I am doing

```
response.setHeader("pragma", "no-cache");              
response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");             
response.setHeader("Expires", "0"); 
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/DEP/loginHelix";
```

The issue is that once I logout and I do browser back I land on the page which I entered after logging in.Browser back should not have worked.JSESSIONID cookie is also not getting deleted.

Comment: Browser back always works (if you don't disable caching from the start, it will simply retrieve the page from the browser cache), also what use are those headers one a redirect, as the redirect leads to a new request (with new headers etc). So not sure why you have this overridden `LogoutSuccessHandler`

Comment: Great observation. I should not be using sendRedirect. Let me do a call to super.onLogoutSuccess(request,response,authentication). How can I redirect the user to a custom page. Also will it take care of the session. Why is delete-cookies tag not working.I still see these cookies.

Comment: The `SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler` already does a redirect and basically your added headers don't do anything. So why this custom class, simply set the `logout-success-url` property on the `logout` element. As mentioned navigating back to the previous page will always work because of browser caches (unless you took care of caching from the start!). Depending on the servlet container explicit cookie removal might not work, the session-invalidation should work though.

Comment: Point taken.
I have to perform certain logic on a third party while logging out.Also I need to delete certain cookies which I am creating while doing login. Can you guide me on how to achieve this? I believe we will have to write a custom logout handler.

Comment: If you need to do some logic then simply implement a `LogoutHandler` instead of a `LogoutSuccessHandler`. The `LogoutHandler` is the place to do something when a logout is request, the `LogoutSuccessHandler` is for after that. As stated removing cookies might not work on certain application servers (this is also mentioned in the reference guide if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: Great. I have done the change. For invalidating session I am doing
try {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }

        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(LogLevel.INFO, "Problem logging out.");
    }

But still the session does not get invalidated.
2. I am setting the cookieMaxAge to 0 and cookieName to null but still the cookies persist.

Comment: Why are you hacking around yourself... Spring is already doing that for you with its default filters... Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel?...